# VSCode - identifier "size_t" is undefined

Tags: c, size-t

I'm writing a code for a simple program that calculates the perimeter of a polygon when its given the amount of sides it has and the length of each side as homework, problem is that when I do `for (size_t i = 0; i < sidesnumber; i++)` it gives me an error on `size_t` saying "identifier "size_t" is undefined". I have already tried also including the library `stddef.h` but it stays the same.

This is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sidesnumber = 0;
int sides[100];
int results;

main()
{
    printf("Number of Sides\n");

    sidesnumber = getchar();
    sidesnumber -= 48;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sidesnumber; i++)
    {
        /* code */
        getchar();
        sides[i] = getchar();
        sides[i] -= 48;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sidesnumber; i++)
    {
        /* code */
        results += sides[i];
    }

    printf("The perimeter is:%d", results);
}
```

I'm using MinGW on Windows 10.

*Code of all the .jsons I'm currently using*

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile C File",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasename}.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Run C File",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": ".\\${fileBasename}.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/mingw64/bin"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasename}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile C File"
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "C:\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tr1",
                "C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++",
                "C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include\\c++\\tr1",
                "C:\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include\\c++",
                "C:\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: What happens if you delete that thing which looks like `size_t` and type it in again? I am asking to make sure that there is no weird character representation getting in the way.

Comment: I am just wildly curious: why do you need `size_t` at all? Why isn't `int` (which you already use) good enough?

Comment: Now, MinGW doesn't know what `"%zu"` format specifier is for `size_t` by default in 32-bit mode. So it should find the type `size_t` fine. I just tried on an older TDM MinGW with gcc 4.9.2 and it finds the type fine. Make sure the path to `.../MinGW/bin` is in your PATH.

Comment: I tried to convince my tdm gcc 4.9.2 to stick to c89 (within CodeBlocks). I only got it down to c99 and it finds size_t w/o problems. @DavidC.Rankin Do you know a way of getting down to c89? (I am referring to your deteled comment, out of curiosity.)

Comment: Please show us the command lines that compile your source. VS Code should have an output for this. Trying with a similar MinGW on Windows 10 gives only other warnings, but not this error.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hmm, I thought it was C89, by default..  but I guess it is C90 by default, e.g. `"warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]"` when I compile a simple test with `"gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o bin\stdio_size_t stdio_size_t_test.c"`

Comment: Pedro. As you can see, we really tried to reproduce your problem. Please do not take it wrong if I ask you to double check that the code you are using at home is identical to the one shown here. No typo (size-t, size_l, ...) no weird characters (ßize_t), not error message on other line than you describe here? ...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ah I get it, you thought that C89 is what you get if you do NOT explicitly influence it via options. (My mistake, should have been clear from your phrasing.) But you tried and found out it seems C90. Thanks.

Comment: C89 === C90....

Comment: With Visual Studio / Visual C not understanding it, it's most likely because the compiler doesn't understand the C99 / C++ `for (type var = val; test; increment)` style of `for` loop.  It's an odd error message, but I'd strongly suspect that's most of the problem.  Define `size_t i;` at the top of the function, and remove `size_t` from the loop controls — there's a moderate chance it will compile.

Comment: @Yunnosch I copied the code exactly from my own VSCode, it is exactly what I have myself. Also, replying to your first comment, I did try to rewrite size_t, I also made an entire different code which I completely typed myself entirely, including size_t and the issue persists.

Comment: I'm a very rookie programmer, so I really don't know how to provide any more information than this.    I edited my original post to provide all the codes for my current in use .jsons

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My biggest issue here is that the person who originally wrote the code (classmate) had 0 problems when he first wrote the code and used `size_t`, and we are all using the same IDE, compiler, and everything, we literally setup our IDE's the same exact way, he doesn't have an issue with `size_t`, but I happen to do.

Comment: It's a wild guess, but it *may* be related to this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3026 .

Comment: I can't help much guessing how you get a different result from your classmate on nominally the same IDE setup.  There must be some critical difference, but I've no idea where to look.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I ran the compiler, and regardless of the error on `size_t` it compiles without no issues, and it works perfectly on the debugger, so I'm guessing it's just a syntax error?

Comment: Pedro. Well done. Sorry that it did not help.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Interesting and I tend to believe you (honestly, no sarcasm intended). Still, could you provide a quote?

Comment: "C90

The same standard as C89 was ratified by the International Organization for Standardization as ISO/IEC 9899:1990, with only formatting changes,[2] which is sometimes referred to as C90. Therefore, the terms "C89" and "C90" refer to essentially the same language." - wikipedia.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you, and no worries, you still guided me through.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t says that any of `<stddef.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>` or `<time.h>` should work for defining *size_t*.

Comment: Are you sure you are using GCC as the compiler? The error message `identifier "size_t" is undefined` in your question doesn't look like a GCC error message. Could you please copy-paste the full message (all lines, not only the error message) you are getting?

Comment: @pts It seems not clear whether the IDE or the compiler produces this error. Pedro commented the last time more than 3 years ago, and it could be a school assignment. I'm afraid that we will not see any update here.

Comment: I've VTC as not reproducible since it seems unlikely to be updated with the same tools that were in use at the time of the post

Comment: The code in the question has syntax errors in all versions of C: since C99 you cannot omit the return type of `main` ; but prior to C99 you cannot declare variables in the `for` loop control expressions

Answer (score -3):

If you are only concerned about the squiggles under **size_t** in vscode, you can use **std::size_t** instead.

Comment: the question is about C, not C++